# speed up unparallelizable for loop in pytorch code

Tags: pytorch

I built a network in pytorch, and upon profiling, saw that ~90% of the work is done in a for loop in one of my blocks. The problem is that this loop is not parallelizable, due to dependency on the previous values that were masked by mask1 (see MWE bellow).

I tried compiling it using torch.jit.script and the speedup was negligible at ~0.5s. I am doing the minimal amount of work in the loop, anything else was vectorized. Attached is a MWE with the sizes of tensors that I am working with.

I read that C++ is supposed to be faster. Will writing the code in C++ be better than what torchscript does? Is there any other way to considerably improve the runtime of the loop? Thanks.

```
import torch
import time

n = 11300
f = 7800
batch_size = 10
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

inp1 = torch.randint(0, n, size=[batch_size, n, 4], device=device)
inp2 = torch.randint(0, n, size=[batch_size, f, 3], device=device)
inp3 = torch.randint(0, f, size=[batch_size, n, 2], device=device)
inp4 = torch.randint(0, n, size=[batch_size, n, 2], device=device)
inp5 = torch.randint(0, n, size=[batch_size, n, 2], device=device)


batch_list = torch.arange(batch_size, device=device)

mask1 = torch.ones([batch_size, n], dtype=torch.bool, device=device)
mask2 = torch.ones([batch_size, n], dtype=torch.bool, device=device)
mask3 = torch.ones([batch_size, n], dtype=torch.bool, device=device)

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(n):
    if torch.all(~mask1[:, i]):
        continue
    batch_list_tmp = batch_list[mask1[:, i]]
    mask2[mask1[:, i], i] = False
    mask3[batch_list_tmp.unsqueeze(-1), inp1[:, i][:, ::2][batch_list_tmp]] = 0
    mask1[batch_list_tmp, i] = False
    concat_list_1 = inp5[
        batch_list.unsqueeze(-1), inp4[batch_list.unsqueeze(-1), inp1[batch_list, i]].view([batch_size, -1])]
    concat_list_2 = inp5[batch_list.unsqueeze(-1).unsqueeze(-1), inp4[
        batch_list.unsqueeze(-1).unsqueeze(-1), concat_list_1[batch_list]].view([batch_size, 8, -1])[
        batch_list]].view([batch_size, 8, -1])
    closure = inp2[batch_list.unsqueeze(-1).unsqueeze(-1),
                           inp3[batch_list.unsqueeze(-1).unsqueeze(-1),
                              concat_list_2[batch_list]].view(batch_size, 8, -1)[batch_list]].view([batch_size, 8, -1])
    mask1[batch_list_tmp.unsqueeze(-1), closure.view([batch_size, -1])[batch_list_tmp]] = False
end_time = time.time()

print(end_time-start_time) # takes ~5-7 seconds on server
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to move this operation off-process. For instance, if this was a preprocessing step before training, you could have a pool of workers pre-processing multiple batches ahead of time and queuing them such that the wait time to dequeue the first ready batch was negligible or much smaller.

Another thought is that it may actually be possible top deserialize your for loop by changing the sequence of operations (i.e. there are many sequences of operations to accomplish a final result, some of which may be parallelizable). Without a description of what you're trying to accomplish, it's hard to tell whether this may be the case here.

Comment: What I am trying to do is create three masks (mask1,mask2,mask3), These masks are generated dynamically based on the calculated features, and the current state of mask1 (hence the for loop).
unfortunately, this is not a preprocess, because the masking is performed based on calculated features.
And I can't deserialize due to the current iteration needing to have the current mask1 value..

Comment: Doesn't really matter if it's preprocessing per se you should still be able to do the task with multiple worker processes. I just used preprocessing as an example

Comment: Ok, But will the workers really be parallel? they all need to reference and update mask1, which I expect would basically cause a them to act serially.

Comment: I'm suggesting to parallelize across batches rather than across operations within the batch (i.e. if you have many chunks that take 7 seconds each, do them at the same time)